# Problem with Py_stringmatching GeneralizedJaccard

Tags: python, string, text, compare, similarity

I'm using `GeneralizedJaccard` from `Py_stringmatching` package to measure the similarity between two strings.
According to [this document](http://anhaidgroup.github.io/py_stringmatching/v0.4.x/GeneralizedJaccard.html):

> ... If the similarity of a token pair exceeds the threshold, then the
> token pair is considered a match ...

For example for word pair 'method' and 'methods' we have:

```
print(sm.Levenshtein().get_sim_score('method','methods'))
>> 0.8571428571428572
```

The similarity between example word pair is 0.85 and greater than 0.80 ,So this pair must considered a match and I expect that the final GeneralizedJaccard output for two near-duplicate sentences to be **equal to 1** but it's 0.97:

```
import py_stringmatching as sm

str1 = 'All tokenizers have a tokenize method'
str2 = 'All tokenizers have a tokenize methods'
alphabet_tok_set = sm.AlphabeticTokenizer(return_set=True)
gj = sm.GeneralizedJaccard(sim_func=sm.Levenshtein().get_sim_score, threshold = 0.8)

print(gj.get_raw_score(alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str1),alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str2)))

>> 0.9761904761904763
```

So what is the problem?!

Comment: I don't know how to say it, but may be the problem is that you do not understand the   document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that after considering the pair as a match, the similarity score of that pair used in Jaccard formula instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

If two strings are not a match you get "0" as a result. If they match, then you get the similarity score.

```
# threshold 80%
gj80 = sm.GeneralizedJaccard(sim_func=sm.Levenshtein().get_sim_score, threshold=.8)

print(gj80.get_raw_score(alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str1), alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str2)))
# Out: 0.9761904761904763


# threshold 100% (string can only match even if they're the same)
gj100 = sm.GeneralizedJaccard(sim_func=sm.Levenshtein().get_sim_score, threshold=1)

print(gj100.get_raw_score(alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str1), alphabet_tok_set.tokenize(str2)))
#Out: 0.0
```

Comment: As I said the Normalized Levenshtein similarity between pair 'method' and 'methods' is about 0.85 and greater than the threshold 0.80. So must considered a match in final  Generalized Jaccard for two sentences.

Comment: @ARZ oh I see! Right, with that threshold you'd expect 1 even if two tokens are not the same ...